# Python question -- lambda version of a recursive combinations function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, combinations, permutation

Okay so I have the following simple Python 3 function that does exactly what it's supposed to do:

```
def comb(a):
    if len(a)==0:
        return[[]]
    else:
        p=[]
        for c in comb(a[1:]):
            p+=[c,c+a[:1]]      
        return p
```

which correctly produces

```
>>> comb([1,2,3])
[[], [1], [2], [2, 1], [3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Motivated by nothing other than a desire to better my own understanding of recursive functions, I tried to see if I could turn this simple function into a lambda.  First thing I tried was various versions of:

```
comb=lambda a:[[]]if len(a)==0 else[[c,c+a[:1]]for c in comb(a[1:])]
```

Which, obviously, didn't work.  Then I took a step back and just tried to change the syntax of the original function like:

```
def comb(a):
    return[[]]if len(a)==0 else[p for p in[[c,c+a[:1]]for c in comb(a[1:])]]
```

Which also doesn't work, like at all.  I tried all kinds of different arrangements but to no avail.  Obviously the original function is the most useful and easiest to read, I'm only asking about this to better my own python understanding. I'm normally pretty good at this game when recursion isn't involved so I'm just trying to understand what it is I'm missing here.

Comment: What is the goal of your question? To write the function using a ``lambda``? To write the function using a list comprehension? Note that ``lambda`` expressions are generally poor for recursion, since recursion inherently relies on calling the function *by name* – the point of ``lambda`` is to create unnamed functions. You can assign a ``lambda`` to a name, but it defeats the purpose.

Comment: `+=` is like list.extend(), it flattens your list, unlike your list comp

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Per my original question, the goal is simply to increase my own understanding of recursive functions and list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to rewrite the function to lambda one-liner, you can do it using `sum()` for example:

```
comb = lambda a: [[]] if len(a)==0 else sum(([c,c+a[:1]] for c in comb(a[1:])), [])

print(comb([1, 2, 3]))
```

Prints:

```
[[], [1], [2], [2, 1], [3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

NOTE: The above solution is not very readable. The classic function is better.

---

Thanks @Chris_Rands, solution with `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

comb = lambda a: [[]] if len(a)==0 else [*chain.from_iterable([c,c+a[:1]] for c in comb(a[1:]))]
```

Comment: Wow, with the quickness!  Also, I fully understand how the classic function is better for production code.  This is for my own understanding, mostly so that I don't get confused when I encounter stuff like this in the wild since not everything I wind up troubleshooting is readable. Let me noodle on this for a bit but I think this is exactly the type of thing I was looking for.

Comment: ok so... sum() will flatten a list such that `sum([[1, 2], [3, 4]], []) == [] + [1, 2] + [3, 4]` ... I feel like I knew that but it didn't really click how I could use that in certain situations like this until now.  Good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the list comprehension.

`[[c,c+a[:1]]for c in l]`  is a list of length `len(l)` whose elements are lists are with 2 elements.  What you want is a list of length `2*len(l)`, which is the flattened version of this.

```py
comb=lambda a:[[]]if len(a)==0 else[c+a[:1]for c in comb(a[1:])] + comb(a[1:])
```

Works but can probably be improved because it makes 2 calls to comb each time, when only 1 is needed.

Comment: Cool!  Like you said probably not as 'optimal' as @andrej-kesely 's version but your answer definitely better for helping me to see what the issue was with my failed attempts.  Very good illustration, extremely helpful, thank you!